# List only files from subfolders of specified folder

Tags: cmd

This question might have a simple solution, but I just cannot find it.

Let's say I'm using the DIR command to produce a list of .txt files in the folder "E:\Documents". How can I make sure that only the .txt files one level below "E:\Documents" are listed (i.e. in a direct subfolder) and not the files in "E:\Documents" itself. "E:\Documents\\" or "E:\Documents\*\" doesn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b/ad') DO IF EXIST ".\%%i\*.txt" DIR ".\%%i\*.txt"
```

That's if you want the output in DIR format - with headers

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad') DO IF EXIST ".\%%i\*.txt" (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('DIR /b ".\%%i\*.txt" ') DO ECHO ".\%%i\%%q"
  )
```

if you want just the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without `dir`:

```
for /d %%d in ("C:\basedir\*") do for %%f in ("%%~fd\*.txt") do echo %%~ff
```

If you need not only the file names, but also detail information about the files, add the respective qualifiers, e.g.:

```
for /d %%d in ("C:\basedir\*") do for %%f in ("%%~fd\*.txt") do echo %%~azff
```

- `a` → attributes of the file
- `t` → timestamp of the file
- `z` → size of the file

See `help for` for details.